# Custom annotation won't update on the map view when it's updated

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm doing the `willChangeValueForKey` and `didChangeValueForKey` calls but even with them the mapView delegate never runs through the `mapView: viewForAnnotation:` to update the thing. How can I force the `MKAnnotation` to be updated?

The `annotationView.image` isn't being updated when the image changes, nor is the `annotationView.image`. As far as I can tell by my NSLog line the `mapView: viewForAnnotation:` isn't being called again when the `MKAnnotation` is updated.

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *currentSubTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *pin;

- (NSString*) title;
- (NSString*) subtitle;
- (id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c;
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) getCoordinate;
- (void) addPlace:(MapAnnotation*) place;
- (int) placesCount;
- (void) cleanPlaces;
- (UIImage *) getPin;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"

@interface MapAnnotation()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *places;
@end

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate      = _coordinate;
@synthesize currentTitle    = _currentTitle;
@synthesize currentSubTitle = _currentSubTitle;
@synthesize places          = _places;
@synthesize category        = _category;
@synthesize pin             = _pin;


- (NSString*) subtitle {
    if ([self placesCount] == 1) {
        return self.currentSubTitle;
    }
    else{
        return @"";
    }
}


- (NSString*) title {
    if ([self placesCount] == 1) {
        return self.currentTitle;
    }
    else{
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d places", [self placesCount]];
    }
}


- (void)addPlace:(MapAnnotation *)place {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    [self.places addObject:place];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
}


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)getCoordinate {
    return self.coordinate;
}


- (void)cleanPlaces {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
    [self.places removeAllObjects];
    [self.places addObject:self];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"subtitle"];
}


- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
    self.coordinate=c;
    self.places=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    return self;
}


- (int)placesCount {
    return [self.places count];
}


- (UIImage *)getPin {
    // begin a graphics context of sufficient size
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(26, 26);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);

    // get the context for CoreGraphics
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    // Draw Dot
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectInset(imageRect, 4, 4);
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor yellowColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    // Dot Content
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, transform);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
    CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(ctx, 1.7);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.0];
    if ([self placesCount] != 1) {
        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self placesCount]];
        CGSize stringSize = [label sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
        [label drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(size.width / 2 - stringSize.width / 2, size.height / 2 - stringSize.height / 2)
            withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    } else {
        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.pin];
        CGSize stringSize = [label sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
        [label drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(size.width / 2 - stringSize.width / 2, size.height / 2 - stringSize.height / 2)
            withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
    }


    // make image out of bitmap context
    UIImage *retImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    // free the context
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return retImage;
}

@end
```

**mapView: viewForAnnotation:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyAnnoation"];
    if(!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyAnnoation"];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    if ([(MapAnnotation*)annotation placesCount] == 1) {
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    annotationView.image = [(MapAnnotation*)annotation getPin];
    NSLog(@"%@", [annotation title]);

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: Only the annotation view's _callout_ automatically observes changes to the title and subtitle.  The view itself (including the image) does not observe those properties and will not automatically update the view.  Are you using a custom annotation view (as well as a custom annotation)?  Is the view observing changes to title and subtitle?  Show the viewForAnnotation method.  Alternatively, you can manually update the view when you update the annotation.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina - No custom view at the moment. My issue is that I'm changing annotation icon, thats not updating. I'll add some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, except for `title` and `subtitle`, changes to annotation properties don't automatically cause the view to get updated.

Changing the `title` and `subtitle` will automatically update the callout while it's displayed as long as the changes result in KVO notifications (eg. if done using the default setter with `ann.title = xxx` or by manually issuing KVO notifications as the code in the question is doing since you have custom getters).

To automatically update the image, you'd probably need to use a custom annotation view that observes changes to the underlying annotation's properties and refreshes itself (in `init` call `addObserver`, in `observeValueForKeyPath` update image, in `dealloc` call `removeObserver`).  You could also probably do it using non-KVO methods such as custom notifications or delegates (but still using a custom annotation view).

With the existing code, a quick and manual way to update the annotation view without creating a custom annotation view and using KVO, etc. is to obtain the annotation's current view right after the annotation is updated and update the `image` property.  This should work as long as the code in `viewForAnnotation` has the same logic for setting the `image`.

I assume somewhere in the app (sometime *after* the annotation is already added), it is updating the places in the annotation by calling `addPlace`.  After that, you can try the following:

```
[someExistingAnnotation addPlace:anotherPlace];

//obtain the current view of someExistingAnnotation...
MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView viewForAnnotation:someExistingAnnotation];

//update its image property to force refresh...
av.image = [someExistingAnnotation getPin];
//also set canShowCallout (it might have been NO)
```

Unrelated but the current `viewForAnnotation` doesn't properly handle possible view re-use and/or annotation types other than your custom annotation (such as the user location blue dot which would cause the current code to crash).  I suggest changing it to this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MapAnnotation class]])
    {
        //annotation is NOT a "MapAnnotation", return nil for default view...
        return nil;
    }

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyAnnoation"];
    if(!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyAnnoation"];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }

    //update view's annotation to current in case it's being re-used
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    if ([(MapAnnotation*)annotation placesCount] == 1) {
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else {
        annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
    }

    annotationView.image = [(MapAnnotation*)annotation getPin];
    NSLog(@"%@", [annotation title]);

    return annotationView;
}
```